# Neo4j 3.5 - Searching for relationship only is very slow on my 12B relationship graph - how do I increase performance?

Tags: performance, neo4j, relationship

I have about 12,000 distinct relationship types, in a 250M node, 12B rel graph.

I sometimes wish to run a query such as:
match (n)-[r]-(m) where type(r)="located_in" return n,r,m limit 10;

to return everything with a located_in relationship.
This is very slow - the above takes hours, on a large system with plenty memory and optimised Java memory settings for this DB.

Do I need some kind of relationship index or is the query poor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the performance of your query significantly by adding labels to the nodes as well as relationships, which reduces noticeable the relevant amount of nodes and relationships to search. A further performance gain you can achieve by returning only the attributes you really need instead of the whole nodes.

```
MATCH (n:TypeA)-[r:LOCATED_IN]->(m:TypeB) RETURN n.attributeA, r, m.attributeB LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at an EXPLAIN of the query, you'll notice this is doing an AllNodesScan to find your starting nodes, so this is matching to all the nodes in your graph and expanding all the relationships in your graph.

As ThirstForKnowledge remarked, adding labels into your graph and using labels in your query will change this to a NodeByLabelScan, so it will only visit all nodes with the given label.

Neo4j does not support relationships in the schema index, although Neo4j 3.5.x does allow you to create a full text index which you could use to index properties on relationships of a particular type. That may aid your lookup, but you haven't shown that you want specific properties on this kind of relationship.